# Add multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000, Can this code be optimised. Project Euler #1

Tags: c#, beginner, programming-challenge

I have seen some solution here for the same problem, [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31051/please-review-my-solution-to-project-euler-program-1) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51093/finding-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000) I have found better ways to solve this problem. I just want to know how good or bad my code and way of approaching this problem is.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; 3 * i < 1000; i++)
        {
            sum += 3 * i;

            if (5 * i < 1000 && (5 * i) % 3 != 0)
            {
                sum += 5 * i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum );
    }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(sum + "");` looks weird, why don't you just `Console.WriteLine(sum);`?

Comment: Please do not edit the code in the question, unless it was a copy-error from the actual code you have. Removing mistakes as they are pointed out, makes the answers no longer relevant for future readers - there's nothing shameful about posting "bad" code in code-review; it's what it's here for :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this solution but it is not really what project euler is searching for. @AlanT provided a good reference solution to this problem.

Comment: When you ask about optimizations problems, please get in the habit of saying *what* you want to be optimized. The optimal program in terms of speed is `class P { static void Main() { System.Console.WriteLine("233168"); } }` but I think that would not be satisfying to you! What exactly do you wish to be "optimal"?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the goal is here, because even if we allow the upper bound to vary this can be computed in constant time, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You may want to consider adding the `project-euler` tag as well

Comment: I added the same tag as you mentioned but it got changed to programming-challenge. This might be because not many people know about project-euler.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The main problem

The main issue here is that you define `i` in function of it being a "factor of 3", and then also try to use this number as a "factor of 5". This doesn't make any sense - as there is no inherent relationship between being a threefold and a fivefold number.

It would've made sense if you were doing it for 3 and 6, for example, because 3 and 6 are related:

```
//i*3 is obviously always a multiple of 3
sum += 3 * i;

if ((3*i) % 2 == 0)
{
    //Now we know that i*3 is also a multiple of 6
}
```

But that is not the case here.

---

### The `for` loop's readability

I understand your idea, you wanted to only iterate over factors of three which keep the multiple under 1000. While I will suggest to change this approach (later in the answer), your approach could've been written in a much more readable manner:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i+=3 )
```

This will iterate over `i` values of `0,3,6,9,12,15,...` and will skip all values inbetween.

The benefit here is that you don't need to work with `i*3` all the time, you can just use `i` itself.

*You will need to iterate over the multiple of 5 separately. However, should you keep using this approach, I would always suggest splitting these loops anyway.*

---

### The algorithm

Your approach works, but it's not the easiest approach. If I put your approach into words:

> *Add every multiple of 3 to the sum.*
>
> *Also add the multiple of 5, but only if it's still below 1000, and it's not already divisble by 3.*

The issue here is in how you handle the multiples of five. You're working with an `i` that is defined as the allowed values for threefolds. For any i > 200, you're effectively having to manually exclude this value. **You're using a different approach for the 5 than you are using for the 3, even though the logic is exactly the same**. That's not a reusable approach.

Secondly, there is a **readability problem**. Your code should be trivially readable, and I simply wasn't able to understand your intention. I had to google what the question was before I could understand what your code was trying to achieve.

So let me offer a better approach, first putting it into words:

> - Check every number from 0 to 1000 (not including 1000)
> - **If** it is divisible by 3 **or** it is divisible by 5, **then** add it to the sum.

This can be put into code, step by step:

```
// Check every number from 0 to 1000 (not including 1000)
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var isDivisibleBy3 = i % 3 == 0;
    var isDivisibleBy5 = i % 5 == 0;

    //If it is divisible by 3 or it is divisible by 5
    if(isDivisibleBy3 || isDivisibleBy5)
    {
        //then add it to the sum
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

Note how the code exactly mirrors my algorithm description.

You don't *need* to use the booleans. I simply added them to simplify the example. `if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)` would be equally okay to use because it's still reasonably readable.

If the calculations become more complex, I suggest always using the booleans so you neatly break your algorithm down to small and manageable steps. It will do wonders for your code readability, and it does not impact performance (the compiler will optimize this in a release build).

---

### A LINQ variation

This can be further shortened using LINQ:

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(0,1000)
              .Where(i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
              .Sum();
```

LINQ is just a nicer syntaxt, but it uses a `for`/`foreach` iteration in the background, so I suspect it won't be much more performant than the previous example. But I do consider this highly readable.

---

### Maximizing performance

The previous suggestion maximizes readability, but it does so at the cost of performance, as it now has to loop over 1000 values and evaluate them all. You already linked several other answer that clearly dive deeper into the code in order to maximize the performance, I hope you can see that this dramatically impacts the readability.

[For example](https://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-1/):

```
public void Solve(){
    result = SumDivisbleBy(3,999)+SumDivisbleBy(5,999)-SumDivisbleBy(15,999);
}

private int SumDivisbleBy(int n, int p){
    return n*(p/n)*((p/n)+1)/2;
}
```

By itself, I would have no idea what this code does. I can sort of understand the intention of `Solve()`, but it's not quite apparent how `SumDivisbleBy()` works.

`SumDivisbleBy()` has effectively become **impossible to maintain**. If you needed to introduce a change, you would effectively have to reverse engineer it before you can alter it. This means that starting from scratch is the better option, which is clearly not a good thing.

However, when performance is the main focus, this is acceptable. I would, however, strongly urge you to **document the algorithm in comments** specifically to help future readers in understanding how/why this works.

Note that **AlanT**'s answer contains a more readable variant of the `SumDivisbleBy()` method, which already helps a lot with understanding the algorithm. The clear naming used clarifies **what** the algorithm does, which is the main goal of writing readable code (explaining *why* something works is only a secondary goal and not always required).

Comment: How about using two counters, one with `i+=3` and the other one with `j+=5`? Wouldn't it be even more efficient without the `%`?

Comment: @t3chb0t: Sure but then you have to iterate twice. I haven't crunched the numbers on it but it seems to be a "pick your poison" type deal. Either iterate twice, or iterate once and validate the numbers. Besides, if you're going for performance, you're _waaaay_ better off with the `SumDivisbleBy` example I linked, as this only requires one computation per divisor (3 computations) in total) and no iteration at all.

Comment: @t3chb0t: A propos, if you use the `i+=3` approach, you will always have to have a second `i+=5` loop. OP's code relies on the "factors of three" (from 0 to 333) inherently including all "factors of five" (from 0 to 200). Using the `i +=3` approach, `i` is no longer a list of "factors of three" but rather "**multiples** of three", which no longer inherently include all "multiples of five"; thus requiring you to iterate those separately.

Comment: Not exactly... I was thinking about a single `for` loop with two variables...

Comment: @t3chb0t: I don't see how that would work unless you then use a combined condition, i.e. `for(int i = 0, j=0; i < 1000 || j < 1000 ; i+=3,j+=5)`. While technically possible, I don't see the benefit of doing so. It dramatically lowers readability, and the # of operations is pretty much exactly the same regardless of merging the `for` loops or keeping them separate. If anything, you're going to end up incrementing `j` 333 times (because `i` will be incremented 333 times) while you only need to increment it 200 times, but since the `for` is still working with `i`, it also keeps incrementing `j`.

Comment: @t3chb0t: Additionally, this means you need to add further validation (ensuring you don't add `j` to the sum when it is > 1000) which defeats the purpose of having written a `for` loop that only iterates over **valid** values. So, in short, no, I do not agree that merging the loops is a good idea. Not for readability, not for performance, and not for the intention of the algorithm.

Comment: Well, there is not argument with math... that's why such programming-challenges are stupid anyway because they don't teach you programming at all. If you are not going to brute-force it and have a _magic_ formula you can move on to the next question ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Project Euler is supposed to be for learning mathematics (right now https://projecteuler.net/ contains two mentions of "program" and seven of "math")... why is that "stupid"? It's not magic; it's just the mathematics of the problem. (Sure, this particular program can be solved with brute-force and no mathematics, but that is not true of most of the later problems on the site.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR that's what [khanacademy](https://khanacademy.org) is for... projecteuler, however, I don't know what purpose it has. It doesn't teach you anything. It presents you some meaningless puzzles where the most of them can be solved by some _secret_ or _magic_ formula that boils down to just implementing it in your favourite programming language which is then virtually a no-brainer ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t Project Euler is for getting good mathematical problems, thinking hard about how to solve them in reasonable time, and in the process either discovering the relevant mathematics (number theory, etc) or being induced to learn it. There is nothing "magic" or "secret" about mathematics; you can find it in textbooks or Wikipedia. (As the front page says, Project Euler started as a sub-section on mathschallenge.net .) I think you're pointing out that the challenge is not primarily programming (the programming is almost always the easy part), but it is not intended to be so anyway.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian: How so? `||` (or `|`) is the **OR** operator, whereas `^` is an **XOR**. Numbers that are both multiples of 3 and 5 (e.g. 15) need to be added, and therefore an XOR would not be correct. In OP's code, OP is specifically excluding multiples of 3 and 5 because he doesn't want to add them _a second time_ (he already added them as a multiple of 3 - no need to add them again when checking for multiples of 5). But using the LINQ solution, it's impossible to actually add the same value twice.

Comment: SumDivisibleBy needs comments, but it doesn't need maintaining (and if you mean maintaining in the sense of "translate from C# to Swift", that's trivial). It has the very nice advantage that it works in _constant time_, so when you replace 1000 with 10^18, it will give the correct answer in a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @Flater Oh, you seem to be right, I guess I misread the OP.

Answer (score 11):

I'm afraid that the solution given is not better than the referenced [C one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31051/please-review-my-solution-to-project-euler-program-1) 
(although the C solution could be generalized and made a bit easier to understand)

**Why?**

The code under review has a outer loop that is executed 333 times (with a multiplication in each condition check). We can remove the multiplication to do the job a bit more cheaply

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 333; i++)
```

But, even with the restructured loop we still do

this,  **sum += 3 * i;**, 333 times and then 
this,   **5 * i < 1000 && (5 * i) % 3 != 0**, 333 times

As opposed to

**S1= a*(b+c)/2;**, once  
**s2= k*(i+j)/2;**, once  
**s3= n*(m+o)/2;**, once  
**S= S1 + s2 - s3;**, once

It is a bit of a cheat in the C solution that the various magic numbers are hardcoded; but even allowing for a function to calculate the values

```
var sum3 = SumDivisibleBy(999,3);
var sum5 = SumDivisibleBy(999,5);
var sum15 = SumDivisibleBy(999,15);
var sum35 = sum3 + sum5 - sum15;


private static int SumDivisibleBy(int range, int divisor)
{
    var top = range/divisor;
    var ret = divisor*top*(top+1)/2;
    return ret;
}
```

is a lot cheaper than brute-forcing the solution.

In the original solution, for numbers under 1000, we need to loop 333 times, for numbers under 10000, we need to loop 3333 times,...  It doesn't scale well.  For the other solution, there are the same number of operations each time.

Comment: Multiplication by a constant `3` is cheaper than multiplication by a runtime variable.  With only 2 set bits, and being 1 + a small power of 2, compilers can do this on x86 with a single instruction with 1 cycle latency, e.g. `lea eax, [rcx + rcx*2]`.  Or a smart compiler might just optimize the `3 *i < 1000` into `i <= 333`, because it can prove that's exactly equivalent for the possible range of `i` values (making the multiply not overflow).  It doesn't *hurt* to do this optimization by hand in the source, though.  And +1 for applying Gauss's closed-form sum formula in a nicely readable way.

Comment: @PeterCordes: As far as I'm aware, neither project Euler nor OP are specifying that they are squeezing for performance to that degree. Using a variable renders the code reusable for _any_ divisors, not just 3 and 5. I'm not saying your performance argument is wrong, but it doesn't necessarily outweigh the benefits of a reusable approach.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will bet you any amount of money that any compiler smart enough to optimize a division like that, is also smart enough to inline this code and make it behave no different from having constants.

Comment: @Alexander: I think that *was* the point I was trying to make in my comment: that the suggested optimization to `i <= 333` in the source wouldn't affect the asm because compilers probably already do it.  But those expressions aren't equivalent if you consider integer wrap-around, and the compiler doesn't manage to use range limits to prove that it's still ok.  The point about runtime variable was that the answer suggests that the code is doing "a multiplication in each conditional". `*3` (literal or after constant propagation) is cheaper than `imul` for `* var` with a *runtime* variable value.

Comment: @Alexander: I didn't mean that using C# variables in the source would cause any kind of problem, as long as you're still calling the function with compile-time-constant args.  Constant propagation makes them into constants.  The final code block in this answer is exactly how you should write it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I totally misread it the first time around, and I totally follow now. I agree with your comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Henrik Hansen it helped.
This is optimised code below according to the WIKI. 
But here is the tradeoff, this has to loop 1000 times. where above solution need to run at most 333 times.

```
 using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                if ( i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    sum += i;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but you should read a bit further -:)

Answer (score -2):

```
i=0
i++
if i%3 OR i%5 then sum+=i
else if i%15 then sum-=i
```

---

By the way this would be hardcoded. If you want reusable then wouldn't you:

```
i=0
i++
a = (user input)
b = (user input)
if i%a OR i%b then sum+=i
else if i%(a*b) then sum-=i
```

---

Or something similar to that. Or does this code already account for the duplicate sums. example you don't want to 15+15 because you only need one 15.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].